# How to define one-to-one and many-to-many relationship using SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have searched the documentation but didn't find anything useful. Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: As you would in SQL, define the foreign key constraints and possible association tables.

Comment: you mean using `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship` right?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Could you please point me in the right direction

Comment: No, as the qualified name points out, `relationship()` is an ORM concept, for mapping object relationships to relational ones. In a relational database you define relationships between relations (tables) using foreign key constraints (and possibly additional constraints). In SQLAlchemy Core you represent a foreign key constraint with `ForeignKey` and `ForeignKeyConstraint`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html.

Comment: That means for the many-to-many relationship I have to define the association table just like an ordinary table , Right?

Comment: Yes. Quoting the [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html): "The SQLAlchemy Expression Language presents a system of representing relational database structures and expressions using Python constructs." In other words with Core you do things the relational DB way, expressed in Python.

Answer (score 5):

**One-to-one**

Use one table's id as a foreign and primary key in the other.

Example from [overiq](https://overiq.com/sqlalchemy-101/defining-schema-in-sqlalchemy-core/#one-to-one-relationship)

```
employees = Table('employees', metadata,
    Column('employee_id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('first_name', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('last_name', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('dob', DateTime(), nullable=False),
    Column('designation', String(200), nullable=False),
)

employee_details = Table('employee_details', metadata,
    Column('employee_id', ForeignKey('employees.employee_id'), primary_key=True, ),
    Column('ssn', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('salary', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('blood_group', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('residential_address', String(200), nullable=False),    
)
```

**Many-to-one**

From [SQL Alchemy's official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html):

> In SQLAlchemy as well as in DDL, foreign key constraints can be defined as additional attributes within the table clause, or for single-column foreign keys they may optionally be specified within the definition of a single column. The single column foreign key is more common, and at the column level is specified by constructing a ForeignKey object as an argument to a Column object:

```
user_preference = Table('user_preference', metadata,
    Column('pref_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_name', String(40), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_value', String(100))
)
```

**Many-to-many**

Create a third table with two foreign keys referencing the tables you want to create a relationship between

Example from [overiq](https://overiq.com/sqlalchemy-101/defining-schema-in-sqlalchemy-core/#one-to-one-relationship)

```
posts = Table('posts', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('post_title', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('post_slug', String(200),  nullable=False),
    Column('content', Text(),  nullable=False),    
)

tags = Table('tags', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('tag', String(200), nullable=False),
    Column('tag_slug', String(200),  nullable=False),    
)

post_tags = Table('post_tags', metadata,
    Column('post_id', ForeignKey('posts.id')),
    Column('tag_id', ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)
```

Comment: A bit old, but any idea if the Core has a functionality to automatically fill association tables (as the ORM has)?