# SqlAlchemy Core: define one-to-one relationship multiple time

Tags: database-design, sqlalchemy, database-relations

I have now implemented an events table with relationships to three other tables through One-to-Many .

```
events = Table(
    "events",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("creator", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL")),
    ...
    Column("location_id", ForeignKey(locations.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("activities_id", ForeignKey(activities.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    UniqueConstraint("location_id", "id", name="event_location")
)

users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    ......

activities = Table(
    "activities",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ....

locations = Table(
    "locations",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ....
```

But such a connection does not satisfy the business logic. An event object can only have one creator, location and activity.

Now I want to define one-to-one relationships for **all** ForeignKey fields. I found solution with define ForeignKey as **primary_key=True** ([How to define one-to-one and many-to-many relationship using SQLAlchemy Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800237/how-to-define-one-to-one-and-many-to-many-relationship-using-sqlalchemy-core))
but how to do this with three fields  I don't understand.

Comment: How do you actually retrieve/query the data?

Comment: @van I assume to use pure sql query using JOIN syntax. My question is not about how to get data, but about the correct structure of the relationship between the tables in the database

Comment: @van the query smth like
`SELECT events.id, events.title, json_agg((users.id , users.email)) AS owner_info FROM events  JOIN users  ON users.id=events.creator WHERE events.id = {pk} GROUP BY events.id `
This return me
`{'id': 2, 'title': 'Test', 'owner_info': '[{"f1":1,"f2":"user@example.com"}]'}`

Comment: OK, it has nothing to do with `sqlalchemy`, but assuming you are using `postgresql`, you can just replace your `json_agg(...)` with the following `(json_agg((users.id , users.name))->>0)::json AS owner_info`, in which case you should receive something like: `{'id': 2, 'title': 'Test', 'owner_info': {'f1': 1, 'f2': 'John'}}`. Please note that i added `::json` to the query to return a dict instead of a string for 'owner_info'.

Comment: This way I got
`asyncpg.exceptions.CannotCoerceError: cannot cast type integer to json`

I found that using litle bit another sintax work nice
`(json_agg('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name)::json->>0) AS owner_info`
Thank you for help!